# What replaced Visual Filters in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I tried to use Internet Explorer's "glow" visual filter on a webpage, but it had no effect when I viewed the page in Internet Explorer 9.  I checked the MSDN website and it says Visual Filters and Transitions are deprecated in IE9.  So what is the IE9 equivalent of CSS code like the following?:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.glow(color=black, strength=5);
```

Is there any way at all to achieve decent-looking, readable white-on-white in IE9?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the things filters were used for have been replaced with CSS3. The effect you're looking for (glow) requires the CSS3 `text-shadow` property which, unfortunately, is not available in IE9.

Comment: Whenever I think about the absurdity that is IE9's lack of `text-shadow` support... ("we deprecated this filter but don't have a CSS3 solution yet")

Comment: I agree that is pretty ridiculous.  The `text-shadow` property is what I use for all the other browsers.  I don't even want to know what insanity was behind the decision to continue excluding it from Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: "Whenever I think about the absurdity that is IE9"  "I don't even want to know what insanity was behind the decision" - Notice all threads about IE contain those sentences? There should be a shortcut for that.

Comment: The beta for IE10 will be out soon for Windows 7, so by the time your project is finished and has been running a while, IE10 will be out for public release.

Comment: This is Microsoft's standard response to everything missing in IE. "When the next IE comes out....". But then the next IE is missing other things. (And here we are a year later waiting...)

Answer (score 1):

For now you can use `-ms-filter` such as `-ms-filter: "glow(color=red, strength=5)"`

Small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/nsr4F/

Note that according to [Introduction to Filters and Transitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) , the prefered syntax is to include the PROGID of the filter and using quotes, like `-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color=red, strength=5)"` since some filters will work different depending on the syntax.

More info:
[-ms-filter Attribute | filter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) &
[Visual Filters and Transitions Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532853%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `filter:shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=135,strength=2);`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.glow(color=black, strength=5);
```

works in IE9, there is no problem

Before people are always complaining they should read references.

You have to set this meta Tag to force IE running in IE 9 mode.
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`
you can check the running Mode with document.documentMode

if you do not set this meta tag. IE is running in Quirksmode to support backwards compatibility and then filters only work if you set the Doctype to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

as it was earlier, if you can remember.

Comment: setting `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` will force IE10 and future versions to run as IE9